# Splitting tables from OCI based on values

Tags: php, html, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am querying an oracle database with an SQL query via the OCI connector. I am looking to split the arrays I return based on the values in one column.

[image]

So in this example, based on the values in the "Location" column, I would like the tables separated. I have been able to get one of the locations separated by using     if (($floorid == $row['LOCATION']) and having floor id set to one of the values, but I cannot replicate this for all of the possibilities without duplicating headers. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":getparam", $safeparam1);

$r = oci_execute($stid);

print '<hr>';
print '<table class="style1">';
Print '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Colour</th></tr>';


while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS + OCI_ASSOC)) {
    print '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $item) {
        print '<td>' . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : 
'') . '</td>';
    }

    print '</tr>';
}

print '</div>';

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your SQL to order the results by the `LOCATION` field:

```
order by location
```

Then, in your `while` loop, detect when the value of `LOCATION` changes and start a new table:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":getparam", $safeparam1);

$r = oci_execute($stid);

print '<hr>';
print '<table class="style1">';
print '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Colour</th></tr>';

$location = -1; // keeps track of the location change.

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS + OCI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($location == -1) {
        // seems to be the first row; set $location so we don't end up with an empty first table.
        $location = $row['LOCATION'];
    }

    if ($row['LOCATION'] != $location) {
        $location = $row['LOCATION'];
        // close previous table; start new table.
        print '</table><table class="style1">';
        print '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Colour</th></tr>';
    }

    print '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        print '<td>' . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : '') . '</td>';
    }

    print '</tr>';
}

print '</table>';

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
```

Comment: @JamesPavett Any feedback on this?